# How to debug local NPM dependency (using `npm link`) with source-maps?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, source-maps

I am using babel-cli to compile my local NPM dependency source code.

package.json:

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "babel src --watch -d lib --source-maps inline",
},
```

The local NPM dependency was referenced by my other application. Now I need `npm link` to debug local NPM dependency. How can I debug with source-maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try **source-map-loader** with webpack
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader